# Cross Compiling Python for Embedded Linux - MIPS

Tags: python, linux, gcc

Im trying to install the Cross Compiling Python for Embedded Linux for MIPS with documentation from this website - http://randomsplat.com/id5-cross-compiling-python-for-embedded-linux.html

On step `CC=ppc_6xx-gcc CXX=ppc_6xx-g++ AR=ppc_6xx-ar RANLIB=ppc_6xx-ranlib ./configure --host=ppc-linux --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/python`

my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS show me an error:

```
checking for --enable-universalsdk... no
checking for --with-universal-archs... 32-bit
checking MACHDEP... linux3
checking EXTRAPLATDIR... 
checking machine type as reported by uname -m... x86_64
checking for --without-gcc... no
checking for ppc-linux-gcc... ppc_6xx-gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/user/Downloads/Python-2.7.2':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

here is my config.log http://pastebin.com/v125Sc5S

do some one have ideas, how I can fix that?

Comment: Have you installed the cross compiler, i.e. can you execute `ppc_6xx-g++` from the command line? `./configure: line 3556: ppc_6xx-gcc: command not found` indicates configure cannot run the compiler executable.

Comment: @dhke `ppc_6xx-g++ ` I can´t execute

Comment: Thus, you don't have the cross-compiler installed. I think you need to install the ELDK (or similar), first: http://www.denx.de/wiki/ELDK-5/WebHome

Comment: @dhke errors when Im trying install ELDK
http://pastebin.com/jr02ZUGU